# SAML request authentication with Kong

Tags: aws-api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin

we are using konghq as an API gateway for one of our customers but we are very new to it and therefore don't know how to tackle this authentication issue.

We have to authenticate our services with a SAML token. Our micro services are behind kong which is running on an EC2. The authentication process should be an independent micro services which validates the token from the request and it’s contents against another system. Instead of a service it could also be some serverless function on a k8s cluster. We don't want to use a lambda to stay cloud agnostic.

We were previously using AWS API gateway and lambda authorizers to tackle the scenario. The authorizer validated the token and took care of the authentication process.

I searched all the Kong forums and google but couldn't find a SAML plugin. Most similar is the JWT plugin but it won't work for us.

Is there something similar in Kong or is there development on Kong involved? If yes, are there any existing plugin which are similar or any tutorials related.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Oldfighter

Comment: I am also looking for similar information. Looks like kong doesn't support it. We want to be service provider in SAML workflow